# How to write a byte array to OutputStream of process builder (Java)

Tags: java, io, iostream

```
byte[] bytes = value.getBytes();
Process q = new ProcessBuilder("process","arg1", "arg2").start();
q.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
q.getOutputStream().flush();
System.out.println(q.getInputStream().available());
```

I'm trying to stream file contents to an executable and capture the output but the output(InputStream) is always empty. I can capture the output if i specify the the file location but not with streamed input.

How might I overcome this?

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.  The process you're writing to needs to be reading from standard in -- is it?

Comment: Sorry , The entire program hangs. I think it may be deadlocked. This may be due to the large nature of the data 5 - 10 mb(Log files)

Comment: Are you sure the InputStream you get from ProcessBuilder supports the available method? Most implementations does not support this and return just 0.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your streams with `BufferedInputStream()` and `BufferedOutputStream()`:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29

> Implementation note: It is a good idea for the output stream to be buffered.
>
> Implementation note: It is a good idea for the input stream to be buffered.

Even with buffered streams, it is still possible for the buffer to fill if you're dealing with large amounts of data, you can deal with this by starting a separate thread to read from `q.getInputStream()`, so you can still be reading from the process while writing to the process.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the program you execute only starts its work when it detects the end of its input data. This is normally done by waiting for an EOF (end-of-file) symbol. You can send this by closing the output stream to the process:

```
q.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
q.getOutputStream().close();
```

Try this together with waiting for the process.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if something else may also be wrong here, but the other process ("process") does not even have time to respond, you are not waiting for it (the method available() does not block). To try this out you can first insert a sleep(2000) after the flush(), and if that works you should switch to query'ing q.getInputStream().available() *multiple* times with short pauses in between.

Comment: No this didnt help.The streaming output from the process is being fed into a csv parser. Is it possible for the parser to process the output as it is produced or dose the process have to complete before it can read from the stream.

Comment: I also tried to write to the stream in a loop as I thought the size of the data may have been what the problem was. This produced a broken pipe error message.

Comment: You write "The streaming output from the process is being fed into a csv parser": this makes me think the called program ("process") doesnt produce std-out/console-output at all. Try replacing "process" with a program of which you know it produces console-output, e.g. on windows "help.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to wait, until the process finished.
I implemented something like this this way:

```
public class ProcessReader {

  private static final int PROCESS_LOOP_SLEEP_MILLIS = 100;
  private String result;

  public ProcessReader(Process process) {
    BufferedReader resultReader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder resultOutput = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while (!checkProcessTerminated(process, resultReader, resultOutput)) {
        }
    } catch (Exception ex1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex1);
    }
    result = resultOutput.toString();
}

public String getResult(){
    return result;
}

private boolean checkProcessTerminated(Process process, BufferedReader resultReader, StringBuilder resultOutput) throws Exception {

    try {
        int exit = process.exitValue();
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException ex) {
        Thread.sleep(PROCESS_LOOP_SLEEP_MILLIS);
    } finally {
        while (resultReader.ready()) {
            String out = resultReader.readLine();
            resultOutput.append(out).append("\n");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

I just removed now some specific code, that you dont need, but it should work, try it.
Regards